# Setting class variable options in php

Tags: php

Not sure how to go about setting a one of the three variables before my constructor builds the query object.

```
public $post_type = 'thing';
public $post_status = 'status';
public $query_limit = '-1';


public function __construct (){

    $this->the_query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => $this->post_type,
        'post_status' => $this->post_status,
        'posts_per_page' => $this->query_limit
        ));



}
```

I want to be able to set the options before instantiating a new object.

```
$gallery = new Gallery;
$gallery->$query_limit = '4';
$gallery->build_gallery();
```

I get errors saying I cant access those properties

Comment: If the behaviour of your object depends on variables being set before it's constructed, then they should be injected (or at least over-ridden) in the constructor. Either that, or the call to `WP_Query` needs to be moved to a separate method.

Comment: `$gallery->$query_limit = '4';` is wrong. It should be `$gallery->query_limit = '4';`

Comment: @iainn it runs with defaults, but I want the option to override them if needed.

Comment: You could also just extend the WP_Query class.

Comment: @mrpatg If you're performing the action in the constructor, you won't be able to override them first - the object won't exist before that. They either need to be passed in as arguments to the constructor, or you need to move the actual logic into a later method, which you can call after you've set the properties.

Comment: @iainn ahhh makes sense now, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`$gallery->$query_limit = '4';` is wrong.
Instead it should be `$gallery->query_limit = '4';`.
This is because PHP has variable variables so you can set a variable by the name set in a variable. Eg.

```
$foo = "bar";
$$foo = "hello";
```

This will set the variable `$bar` equal to "hello".

See more: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php